# Calling one of child pages of TabbedPage to reach entry text

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, casting, tabbedpage

I know, "It is highly recommended to use MVVM" but I am just trying to understand and learn xamarin.forms structure. So here is the question:
My application is based on TabbedPage which consists of two NavigationPage:

```
<TabbedPage.Children >
    <NavigationPage Title="Search">
        <NavigationPage.Icon>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                <On Platform="iOS" Value="tab_feed.png"/>
            </OnPlatform>
        </NavigationPage.Icon>
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:SearchPage />                
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>

    <NavigationPage Title="Study">
        <NavigationPage.Icon>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                <On Platform="iOS" Value="tab_about.png"/>
            </OnPlatform>
        </NavigationPage.Icon>
        <x:Arguments> <!---->
            <views:AboutPage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</TabbedPage.Children>
```

I am trying to call a child of this tabbedpage from a method created in a different class/view model to reach SearchBar text:

```
    public async void AddToList()
    {
        var mp = (MainPage)App.Current.MainPage;
        var sp = (SearchPage)mp.Children[0]; /// exception related with casting is thrown.
        var Word = sp.WordSearchBar.Text;
        ...
    }
```

SearchPage is defined as below. So I what is the issue creating casting exception. And how I can reach the searcbar text (other than bindings and MVVM)

```
public partial class SearchPage : ContentPage
{....}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mp.Children[0];` is kind of `NavigationPage` not `SearchPage`, so you get the casting exception.

One way to achieve that is create a static property in the `App` class:

```
public partial class `App` : Application
{
    public static AboutPage aboutPageInstance { get; set; }

    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DependencyService.Register<MockDataStore>();
        MainPage = new MainPage();
    }
}
```

Then assign the value in the `AboutPage` and let's say you have a label called `currentLabel` in the `AboutPage`:

```
public partial class AboutPage : ContentPage
{
    public Label currentLabel { get; set; }

    public AboutPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        currentLabel = myLabel;
        App.aboutPageInstance = this;
    }
}
```

Then you can access the label in other ContentPage by:

```
async void AddToList(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (App.aboutPageInstance != null)
    {
        AboutPage about = App.aboutPageInstance;

        about.currentLabel.Text = "kkk";
    }
}
```

[MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) is also a good option to communicate between two different ContentPages.

Comment: Thanks. It is a good shortcut. By the way, as you see "SearchPage" is an argument of NavigationPage. Firtsly, I thought there should be a way to call this from Children[0]. But I couldnt, Is it the way NavigationPage works?

Comment: [NavigationPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.navigationpage) does not have a property called Children. It only has currentPage and rootPage.

Comment: Actually, I meant MainPage.Children[0] and expected to reach NavigationPage and this worked. I thought, if the SearchPage is appended to NavigationPage by X:attribute, we should be able to reach it by a property. Apparently there is no way to do it. Later I learned x:attribute is used for construction purposes and it is not a property. Thanks for support.

Answer (score 0):

In the `AddToList` method you are trying to cast the first child of `MainPage` to `SearchPage`. Anyway, in your XAML, the first child in `<TabbedPage.Children>` is a `NavigationPage` which does - of course - not derive from your `SearchPage`, hence cannot be casted and a `InvalidCastException` is thrown.

*If* you really want to do it this way (learning MVVM right away could be helpful, but if you really want to learn it the hard way, it's fine for me), you would have to access the `NavigationPage` and then access its `CurrentPage`

```
public async void AddToList()
{
    var mainPage = (MainPage)App.Current.MainPage;
    var navigationPage = (NavigationPage)mainPage.Children[0];

    if (navigationPage.CurrentPage is SearchPage searchPage)
    {
        var Word = searchPage.WordSearchBar.Text;
        ...
    }
}
```

I've introduced safe casting with pattern matching because the `NavigationPage.CurrentPage` is subject to change (as opposed to the `MainPage` and the `NavigationPage`) and we don't want our app to crash just because the wrong page is active in the navigation page.

Please note that this way, your pages are very tightly coupled, which is usually considered not a very good thing. Even without MVVM you should think about decoupling your pages, e.g. with [`MessagingCenter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.messagingcenter?view=xamarin-forms), see the Xamarin.Forms [tutorial on loosely coupled components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/communicating-between-loosely-coupled-components). Anyway, you should consider introducing interfaces for your pages in that case, since `MessagingCenter` requires the type of the sender, which would introduce some kind of tight coupling again. Sending the search text to another component could be achieved by calling

```
MessagingCenter.Send<ISearchPage, string>(this, MessengerKeys.SearchTextChanged, searchText);
```

But what exactly would be sensible, strongly depends on your app and there might be a better way.

Comment: Thanks. it was helpful. regarding MVVM you are right, I jast was trying o learn. Actually, AddToList was implemented by binding command property to MVVM. Now I will try to bind also the text of WordSearchBar to MVVM field and see what will happen.